# Paqueteria para conectar r project a Cubos OLAP con instrucciones de MDX

Tags: r

soy nuevo en el sitio,

Mi problema es que tengo un cubo de datos OLAP con el cual solo tengo permisos para acceder con las intrucciones de MDX (microsoft Analysis Services) luego quiero trabajar esos datos en R project para que me sea mas facil hacer las tecnicas estadisticas pero no busco como acceder a ellas, he leido mucha información pero solo encuentro las conexiones a SQL Server,

Microsoft tiene una paqueteria para conectarse es el olapR, pero al tratar de instalarlo en R Version 3.4.1 me dice que no son compatibles, estoy tratando de buscar otras paqueterias que me ayuden a realizar la conexion,

Agradezco mucho sus comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque no intentas conectarte usando el [R Client de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/what-is-microsoft-r-client).
En la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/olapr/olapr) también mencionan que el conector es para SQL Server 2016 y también necesitas tener acceso de lectura al Analysis Services.

Si amplias la información con los mensajes de error de conexión puedes ayudar a entender mucho mejor el problema.

Comment: Revisar [answer].